# How to dye UITableView bottom empty space?

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

I have a table with white empty area at the bottom of table view. But I want this area to be gray. I have added a gray footer but it is too much small.

What shall I do?

[image: What I want]

Comment: ` I added a gray footer but it too small.` How did you do that exactly?

Comment: @Larme, I drag&drop UIView to the UITableView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `tableView's` `backgroundColor` as `gray` color and `tableFooterView` with empty `UIView`

```
self.tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
self.tableView.backgroundColor = .gray
```

Comment: @AlexeySubbota Remove that gray view that you have drag and drop in `tableView` inside the interface builder and put these two lines in `viewDidLoad`.

Answer (score 1):

Add the below lines,

`self.tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()`

It will works perfectly.

Comment: Thank you, it works too but I can accept only one answer.

Answer (score 1):

if its because of tableview footer then use the below delegate methods else if its the background view colour modify you tableview to fit the parent view rect

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

        return UIView()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {

        return 0
    }
```